# Bitmap to Base64 Conversion Not Working

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to call a method I create for converting a Bitmap into a Base64 String and for some reason the encode() method is not working for me.

Here is the method I created to convert an image into a byte array:

```
public byte[] getImageBytes() { 
    byte[] picBytes = null;
    try{
        //ImageButton ppView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        String base64 = profileMap.get("WHOOZNEAR_PROFILEPIC");
        picBytes = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);  //works with android 2.2 and higher
        //byte[] picBytes = Base64.decode(base64);
        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picBytes, 0, picBytes.length);
        //if (bitmap != null )
            //ppView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }       
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "unhandled exception when attempting to set profile image");
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No profile image selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return picBytes;
}
```

Here is the method I created to convert the bitmap into a Base64 String:

```
public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
     String temp = "";
     Bitmap temp_Bitmap = bitmap;
     if (temp_Bitmap != null) { 
         try { 
              ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              temp_Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, baos);
              byte[] b=baos.toByteArray();
              temp=Base64.encodeToString(getImageBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
         }
         catch(Exception e){
              Log.e(LOG_TAG,"[ONACTIVITYRESULT] Could not bind input to the bytearray: " + e.getMessage());
         }
     }
     return temp;
}
```

This is the whole file:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

import java.util.Set;

import java.util.Map.Entry;



/*import javax.jmdns.ServiceEvent;

import javax.jmdns.ServiceInfo;*/




import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Base64;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import android.widget.ImageButton;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;



public class ProfileActivity extends Activity {



private static final int NEAR = Menu.FIRST;

private final static String LOG_TAG = ProfileActivity.class.getSimpleName();

//ServiceInfo info = null;

private static final String TAG = "ProfileActivity";

protected LinkedHashMap<String, String> profileMap;

protected static ArrayList<Entry<String, String>> profileArrayList;

private Set<Entry<String, String>> profileSet;

//private Context context;

protected static final boolean D = false;

protected static byte[] input;



protected ListView profileList;

private TextView nameView;

private TextView tagLineView;

protected ProfileAdapter customAdapter;

private ImageButton buttonReturnToNearby;

private TextView screenNameView;

private Profile profile = new Profile();

private Bitmap profBitmap;



protected static class ProfileAdapter extends BaseAdapter {



    private LayoutInflater mInflater;



    public ProfileAdapter(Context context ) {

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }



    public int getCount() {

        return profileArrayList.size();

    }



    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return profileArrayList.get(arg0);

    }



    public long getItemId(int position) {



        return position;

    }



    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unnecessary calls

        // to findViewById() on each row.

        ViewHolder holder;



        // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need

        // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied

        // by ListView is null.

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.peer_profile_row, null, false);



            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views

            // we want to bind data to.

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.propertyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.propertyName);

            holder.propertyValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.propertyValue);

            //TODO: Put a default view here or something if it is a phone or email

            //holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById();



            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView

            // and the ImageView.

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }



        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.            

        //TODO: Make this correct



        holder.propertyName.setText( profileArrayList.get(position).getKey() );

        holder.propertyValue.setText( profileArrayList.get(position).getValue() );



        return convertView;

    }



    class ViewHolder {

        TextView propertyName;

        TextView propertyValue;

    }



    public boolean isEmpty() {



        return profileArrayList.isEmpty();

    }

};



 /*

public void onStart(){

    super.onStart();

    if (D) {Log.i(TAG, "++++ ON START +++++"); }



}

  */

@Override

public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_display);



    //if (D) {Log.i(TAG, "++++ ON CREATE +++++"); }



    HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();



    try 

    {

        temp = (HashMap<String, String>)  profileMap; 



        //THE LINE BELOW NEEDS TO BE UNCOMMENTED TO RECEIVE THE ATTRIBUTES 4/9/12

        temp = (HashMap<String, String>)  this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("ProfileData"); 

        temp = profile.getAllAttributesIncludingPicture();

        profile.setTagLine(temp.get("TagLine"));

        profile.setProfilePicStr(temp.get("WHOOZNEAR_PROFILEPIC"));

        profile.setWhatIDo(temp.get("What I Do"));

    }

    catch (Exception e)

    {

        Log.e(TAG, "Runtime Exceptions suck");

    }



    if (temp != null) {

        profileMap =  new LinkedHashMap<String, String> (temp);     

        //profileMap = profile.getAllAttributesIncludingPicture();

    }

    else

    {

        Log.e(TAG, "temp HashMap is NULL");

    }



    setProfile(profile);



    screenNameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ab_screen_name);

    screenNameView.setText("Peer Profile");



    buttonReturnToNearby = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_nearby);

    buttonReturnToNearby.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                Log.e(TAG, "commented out call to WhoozNearActivity");

                /*

                if(profileMap.get("Name") != null && profileMap.get("Name").compareTo("Set a new value") != 0

                        && profileMap.get("Age") != null && profileMap.get("Age").compareTo("Set a new value") != 0

                        && profileMap.get("Looking") != null && profileMap.get("Looking").compareTo("Set a new value") != 0){

                    float age = Float.parseFloat(profileMap.get("Age"));

                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), WhoozNearActivity.class);

                    startActivity(mainIntent);

                    //finish();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please, enter values for Name, Age and Looking", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                */

            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

                nfe.printStackTrace();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Value Age is not correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {

                npe.printStackTrace();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }

    });



    setupAdapter();

    setProfile(profile);

    //updateProfileList();  //extra call to update is not required

    setupViews();



    Log.e(TAG, "profile map data after creation: " + profileMap);



    //Log.e(TAG, "Get Profile Pic STR:"+getProfilePicStr());

    //Log.e(TAG, "Get Image STR:"+getImageStr());

}



public void setProfile(Profile profile) {

    this.profileMap = profile.getAllAttributes();

    updateProfileList();

    Log.e(TAG, "profile map data after setProfile: " + profileMap);

}



public String getTagline() { 

    return profileMap.get("TagLine");

}



public String getName() { 

    Log.e(TAG, "Got the NAME!");

    return profileMap.get("Name");

}



/*public void setProfilePic() { 

    Log.e(TAG, "SET THE PROFILE PIC!!");



}*/



public LinkedHashMap<String, String> getProfileMap() { 

    return profileMap;

}



public void setupAdapter() {

    customAdapter = new ProfileAdapter(this);

}



public void setupViews() {



    if (profileList == null) {

        profileList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.profile_list);

        profileList.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    }



    nameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileNameLine);

    nameView.setText(profileMap.get("Name"));

    tagLineView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileTagLine);

    tagLineView.setText(profileMap.get("TagLine"));



    //try to set profile pic, otherwise use default

    try{

        ImageButton ppView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_whooznear);

        String base64 = profileMap.get("WHOOZNEAR_PROFILEPIC");

        //base64 = ConvertandSetImagetoBase64(profile.getSelectedImgPath());

        //Log.e("LOG_TAG", "ProfileActivity Base64 String:"+base64);



        //SET THE LOCAL PROFILE PIC STR

        profile.setProfilePicStr(base64);



        byte[] picBytes = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);  //works with android 2.2 and higher

        //byte[] picBytes = Base64.decode(base64);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picBytes, 0, picBytes.length);

        if (bitmap != null) {

            setProfileBitmap(bitmap);

            ppView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }

    }       

    catch (Exception e)

    {

        Log.e(TAG, "unhandled exception when attempting to set profile image:" + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No profile image selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

/*public String getImageStr() { 

    return profileMap.get("WHOOZNEAR_PROFILEPIC").toString();

}*/

/*public String getProfilePicStr() { 
    return profileMap.get("ProfilePic").toString();
}*/

 /*public String ConvertandSetImagetoBase64(String imagePath) { 
        String base64 = null;
        byte[] input = null;

        try{

            FileInputStream fd = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
            Bitmap bmt = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd.getFD());

            try{                
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Bitmap tmp = ProfileActivity.scaleDownBitmap(bmt, 10, this);
                tmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, stream);
                input = stream.toByteArray();
                base64 = Base64.encodeToString(input, Base64.DEFAULT);

                //LocalProfileActivity.input = input;

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"[ONACTIVITYRESULT] Could not bind input to the bytearray: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("LocalProfile", "Could not load selected profile image");
        }
        return base64;
    }*/

public void setProfileBitmap(Bitmap profBitmap) { 
    this.profBitmap = profBitmap;
}

public Bitmap getProfileBitmap() {
    return profBitmap;
}


public String GetBase64ImgString() { 
    String base64Str = Base64.encodeToString(getImageBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    return base64Str;
}

public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
     String temp = "";
     Bitmap temp_Bitmap = bitmap;
     if (temp_Bitmap != null) { 
         try { 
              ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              temp_Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, baos);
              byte[] b=baos.toByteArray();
              temp=Base64.encodeToString(getImageBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
         }

         catch(Exception e){

              Log.e(LOG_TAG,"[ONACTIVITYRESULT] Could not bind input to the bytearray: " + e.getMessage());

         }

     }

     return temp;

}



public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){

     try{

       byte[] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);

       Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);

       return bitmap;

     }catch(Exception e){

       e.getMessage();

       return null;

     }

}



public byte[] getImageBytes() { 

    byte[] picBytes = null;

    try{

        //ImageButton ppView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon);

        String base64 = profileMap.get("WHOOZNEAR_PROFILEPIC");

        picBytes = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);  //works with android 2.2 and higher

        //byte[] picBytes = Base64.decode(base64);

        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picBytes, 0, picBytes.length);

        //if (bitmap != null )

            //ppView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }       

    catch (Exception e)

    {

        Log.e(TAG, "unhandled exception when attempting to set profile image");

        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No profile image selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



    return picBytes;

}



public void updateProfileList() {



    try

    {



    LinkedHashMap <String, String> temp = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>) profileMap.clone();

    temp.remove("Name");

    temp.remove("TagLine");

    temp.remove("ProfileName");



    profileSet = temp.entrySet();



    }

    catch(NullPointerException e)

    {

        e.printStackTrace();

        Log.i(TAG, "exception in thread: updateProfileList() ... profile map: " + profileMap);

    }







    //Profile personfound = new Profile();



            //personfound.addAttribute("age", info.getPropertyBytes("profilePic"));

            //personfound.addAttribute("name", profileMap.get("name"));

            //personfound.addAttribute("age", info.getPropertyString("age"));

            //personfound.addAttribute("gender", info.getPropertyString("gender"));

            //personfound.addAttribute("name", info.getPropertyString("name"));

    //getProfile(personfound);







    //profileArrayList = new ArrayList( Arrays.asList(profileArray) );

    if (profileArrayList == null)

        profileArrayList = new ArrayList();

    else

        profileArrayList.clear();



    for (Entry<String, String> e : profileSet ) {

        profileArrayList.add(e);

    }

    if (profileList != null)

        if (profileList.getAdapter() != null)

            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    Log.e(TAG, "profile map data after update: " + profileMap + profileMap.get("WHOOZNEAR_PROFILEPIC"));

}



public Profile getProfile(Profile profilePersonFound) { 

    return profilePersonFound;

}



public void onNameClick (View v) {

    return;

}



public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add(0, NEAR, 0, "NearBy").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);

    return true;

}



@Override

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {



   switch (item.getItemId()) {

   case NEAR:

       try {



            /*if(profileMap.get("Name") != null && profileMap.get("Name").compareTo("Set a new value") != 0

                    && profileMap.get("Age") != null && profileMap.get("Age").compareTo("Set a new value") != 0

                    && profileMap.get("Looking") != null && profileMap.get("Looking").compareTo("Set a new value") != 0){

                float age = Float.parseFloat(profileMap.get("Age"));

                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, WhoozNearActivity.class);

                startActivity(mainIntent);

                //finish();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Please, enter values for Name, Age and Looking", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }*/

           String tagline = profileMap.get("TagLine");

           /*NeighborViewModel nv = new NeighborViewModel();

           nv.setNeighborDesc(profileMap.get("TagLine"));  //Try setServiceDesc();

           String name = profileMap.get("Name");

           NeighborViewModel nv = null;

           nv.setNeighborName(name);*/

           Profile profile = new Profile();

           profile.setProfileName(profileMap.get("Name"));

           profile.setTagLine(profileMap.get("TagLine"));



           if (profileMap.get("Name") != null) { 

               //Toast.makeText(this, "In If Statement", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               //Toast.makeText(this, tagline, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               //Intent Call

               //Intent intent = new Intent(this, WhoozNearActivity.class);

               //startActivity(intent);



               //Pass the profile data so that it can be broadcasted in ConnectActivity.java

               Intent myIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,
                   AndroidClient.class);

               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "In ProfileActivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
               myIntent.putExtra("Props", profileMap);
               startActivity(myIntent);  
           }

           else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please, enter values for Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

            nfe.printStackTrace();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Value Age is not correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {

            npe.printStackTrace();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
Bitmap ShrinkBitmap(byte[] file, int width, int height){
    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
       Bitmap bitmap;
       int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
       int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

       if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
       {
        if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
        {
         bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
        } else {
         bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio; 
        }
       }
       bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(file, 0, file.length, bmpFactoryOptions);
    return bitmap;
   }


public static Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap photo, int newHeight, Context context) {
    final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;        

    int h= (int) (newHeight*densityMultiplier);
    int w= (int) (h * photo.getWidth()/((double) photo.getHeight()));

    photo=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, w, h, true);

    return photo;
    }
}
```

Here is the getProfile() method from ProfileDBUtilities.java:

```
public Profile getProfile(int pId) {
    Profile profile = null;
    try {
        // int profileID = pId;
        // profileName = pName;
        Cursor cursor = _activity.managedQuery(
                ProfileDBObject.Profile.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {
                        ProfileDBObject.Profile._ID,
                        ProfileDBObject.Profile.NAME,
                        ProfileDBObject.Profile.PROFILE_NAME }, "_ID = '"
                        + pId + "'", null, ProfileDBObject.Profile._ID);

        profile = new Profile();
        profile.setProfileId(pId);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int nameCol = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ProfileDBObject.Profile.PROFILE_NAME);
        String profileName;
        try {
            profileName = cursor.getString(nameCol);
        }
        // If the profile ID doesn't exist, return the first profile in the
        // DB
        catch (Exception e) {
            cursor = _activity.managedQuery(
                    ProfileDBObject.Profile.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {
                            ProfileDBObject.Profile._ID,
                            ProfileDBObject.Profile.NAME,
                            ProfileDBObject.Profile.PROFILE_NAME }, null,
                    null, ProfileDBObject.Profile._ID);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            nameCol = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ProfileDBObject.Profile.PROFILE_NAME);
            profileName = cursor.getString(nameCol);
        }

        profile.setProfileName(profileName);

        cursor.close();
        // Start grabbing the related attributes
        cursor = _activity.managedQuery(
                AttributeDBObject.Attribute.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {
                        AttributeDBObject.Attribute.ATTR_NAME,
                        AttributeDBObject.Attribute.ATTR_VALUE },
                "PROFILE_ID = '" + pId + "'", null,
                AttributeDBObject.Attribute._ID);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int aNameIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AttributeDBObject.Attribute.ATTR_NAME);
        int aValIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AttributeDBObject.Attribute.ATTR_VALUE);
        String aName;
        String aValue;
        // If there are attributes, add them to the profile
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
            do {
                aName = cursor.getString(aNameIndex);
                aValue = cursor.getString(aValIndex);
                profile.addAttribute(aName, aValue);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Error when getting profile from the db: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return profile;
}
```

Here is the StackTrace:

```
 08-15 07:34:37.141: I/ActivityThread(382): Pub com.iconnexus.client: com.iconnexus.client.ProfileProvider
 08-15 07:34:37.351: D/dalvikvm(382): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 57K, 53% free 2566K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 78ms
 08-15 07:34:41.581: E/ProfileDBUtilities(382): Error when getting profile from the db: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
 08-15 07:34:41.651: E/ProfileActivity(382): profile map data after update: {}null
 08-15 07:34:41.651: E/ProfileActivity(382): profile map data after setProfile: {}
 08-15 07:34:41.651: E/ProfileActivity(382): profile map data after update: {}null
 08-15 07:34:41.661: E/ProfileActivity(382): profile map data after setProfile: {}
 08-15 07:34:41.671: E/ProfileActivity(382): unhandled exception when attempting to set profile image:null
 08-15 07:34:41.711: E/ProfileActivity(382): profile map data after creation: {}
 08-15 07:34:41.711: E/ProfileActivity(382): profile map data after update: {}null
 08-15 07:34:41.721: E/ProfileActivity(382): profile map data after setProfile: {}
 08-15 07:34:41.721: E/ProfileActivity(382): unhandled exception when attempting to set profile image:null
 08-15 07:34:41.991: E/ProfileActivity(382): LocalProfileActivity profileJSON: {"nameValues":{},"profileId":13,"valid":false}
 08-15 07:34:42.061: E/LocalProfile(382): ConvertandSetImagetoBase64: Could not load selected profile image
 08-15 07:34:42.071: E/LocalProfile(382): ConvertandSetImagetoBase64: Could not load selected profile image
 08-15 07:40:23.171: W/KeyCharacterMap(382): No keyboard for id 0
 08-15 07:40:23.193: W/KeyCharacterMap(382): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
 08-15 07:40:24.161: E/ProfileDBUtilities(382): Error when getting profile from the db: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
 08-15 07:40:24.161: E/ProfileActivity(382): profile map data after update: {}null
 08-15 07:40:24.161: E/ProfileActivity(382): profile map data after setProfile: {}
 08-15 07:40:24.592: E/ProfileActivity(382): profile map data after update: {}null
 08-15 07:40:24.621: E/ProfileActivity(382): profile map data after setProfile: {}
 08-15 07:40:24.621: E/ProfileActivity(382): profile map data after update: {}null
 08-15 07:40:24.632: E/ProfileActivity(382): profile map data after setProfile: {}
 08-15 07:40:24.641: E/ProfileActivity(382): unhandled exception when attempting to set profile image:null
 08-15 07:40:24.691: E/ProfileActivity(382): profile map data after creation: {}
 08-15 07:40:24.711: E/AndroidClient(382): Before initEventHandlers
 08-15 07:40:24.711: E/AndroidClient(382): After initEventHandlers
 08-15 07:40:24.721: E/AndroidClient(382): Local Profile Map is null from intent in ConnectActivity
 08-15 07:40:25.101: E/AndroidClient(382): TAGLINE: null
 08-15 07:40:25.101: E/AndroidClient(382): WHOOZNEAR PIC:null
 08-15 07:40:25.111: E/AndroidClient(382): REGEX REPLACEALL:"Ryan"
 08-15 07:40:25.111: E/AndroidClient(382): temp_Bitmap is NULL!!
 08-15 07:40:25.141: E/ProfileActivity(382): unhandled exception when attempting to set profile image
 08-15 07:40:25.141: D/AndroidRuntime(382): Shutting down VM
 08-15 07:40:25.151: W/dalvikvm(382): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iconnexus.client/com.iconnexus.client.AndroidClient}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at android.util.Base64.encode(Base64.java:494)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at android.util.Base64.encodeToString(Base64.java:456)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at com.iconnexus.client.ProfileActivity.GetBase64ImgString(ProfileActivity.java:315)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at com.iconnexus.client.AndroidClient.onCreate(AndroidClient.java:266)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
 08-15 07:40:25.181: E/AndroidRuntime(382):     ... 11 more
 08-15 07:40:27.442: I/Process(382): Sending signal. PID: 382 SIG: 9
```

Comment: So, where are you calling `BitMapToString(Bitmap)`?

Comment: Your logcat describe that there is null pointer exception at 315 line number in ProfileActivity class "ProfileActivity.java:315"

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in your `BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap)` method.

You convert parameter bitmap into byte array (b) and then didn't use it...

```
byte[] b=baos.toByteArray();
temp=Base64.encodeToString(getImageBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Probably you should use that `b` in `incodeToString` method...so it should look like this...

```
byte[] b=baos.toByteArray();
temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

in short, don't call `getImageBytes()` in `encodeToString` Method.

Hope this helps...

If you decide that this answers your question, please mark it as "accepted". This will raise both your and my reputation score.